# What is the difference between <= and := in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am looking the difference between this operators

My opinion is this one performed in execution 
<=

while the other one is used for initialization
:=

is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

`<=` is for signals, and performs non-blocking assignment.

`:=` is for variables.

See: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/sequential.html

Comment: "non-blocking assignment" is not a term used in VHDL. "Postponed assignment" is.